# Adding -gcc_flags to [build/iphone build/extra arguments] causes linking errors. MonoDevelop bug?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am using MonoDevelop version 2.4.2 with iOS SDK 4 installed. I am encountering a problem whereby simply adding -gcc_flags to the project [build/iphone build/extra arguments] setting causes linking errors in MonoDevelop.

This is easily reproducible, just create an empty iPhone Window-based Project. Confirm that it compiles correctly. Then add a simple include path with in [build/iphone build/extra arguments] as follows:

-v -v -v -gcc_flags "-I${ProjectDir}"

With this added, when I try compile I get the following linking errors (I have removed the paths to the temporary directory to make the error messages more readable):

main.m:9:26: error: mono/jit/jit.h: No such file or directory
main.m:10:36: error: mono/metadata/assembly.h: No such file or directory
main.m:11:39: error: mono/metadata/mono-config.h: No such file or directory
main.m:12:38: error: mono/metadata/mono-debug.h: No such file or directory
main.m:13:26: error: monotouch/gc.h: No such file or directory
main.m:14:33: error: monotouch/monotouch.h: No such file or directory

It seems, therefore, with the -gcc_flags option set that MonoDevelop does not seem to find the path to the required mono and monotouch header files. Is this a known problem? Does anyone know a work around for this problem?

I am new to MonoTouch, and so maybe I am doing something wrong here... and if I am, then I would appreciate it if someone could let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can get MonoTouch to compile with -gcc_flags set.

Thanks,

Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MonoTouch and iOS SDK versions are out of sync.  Install MonoTouch 3.2.4 and iOS SDK 4.2.

Comment: Thanks, Geoff. :) You are right, I had MonoTouch 3.2.4 installed, but for some reason only had iOS SDK 4.0 installed. I'm not sure how I managed to download an out-of-date version of Xcode and the SDK, but that is clearly what happened. I now have SDK 4.2 installed and the compile now works correctly with -gcc_flags set. Thanks for your help. :)